# IsAsync =true on ComboBox ItemsSource affects SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous, combobox

I've spent hours trying to figure out what is happening to my selecteditem property of my ComboBoxes and Im pretty sure I know what is causing the problem now, but I just dont understand why this is happening and if there is something I can do about it.

Basically I have a DataGrid with comboboxes in the headers that I use for filtering the DataGrid items. The DataGrid sits in a Tabcontrol and if I select items in the comboxes and switch tab and back the selected items are removed.

This happens only when the ItemsSource of the Comboboxes have the IsAsync property set to True. Otherwise everything works just like I want it to.

To give some more info about the logic:
The comboboxes get their values from a IValueConverter its the same converter for all comboboxes and I pass a ConverterParameter to tell it what to return. The collection sent to the converter is the items shown in the datagrid. 
These values are refreshed (each item has selected parameters updated, the collection is not cleared and recreated) when the tab is activated.

This my xaml for one of the comboboxes:

```
 <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding MadeBy}" ItemsSource="{Binding IssuesView,Converter={StaticResource DataGridFilterableValueConverter}",ConverterParameter=Madeby, IsAsync=true}" SelectionChanged="FilterComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Now, like i described previously, if I set the IsAsync to false the selecteditems stay.

Do I just have to live with this? We work alot with sql-databases and IsAsync really makes the interface alot more snappy. I can live without it in the comboboxes, but I tend to use it as much as I can.

I've seen that ppl have been having problems with the selecteditem and the general solution seems to be placing the SelectedItem before the ItemsSource, but this does not help.

Thanks

Erik

Edit 1:
Here is the xaml of the tabcontrol and tabitem.

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TabControl" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
           <TabItem Header="Granskningssynpunkter" x:Name="IssueTab">
```

..... Lots of code here but nothing that concerns TabControl or TabItem

Comment: Could you add the XAML for the TabControl and TabItem? Mostly because we need to answer the question "Are you doing anything on Loaded of the particular TabControl/TabItem?"

Comment: Try binding to `Text` instead of `SelectedItem`. I've seen this help with similar issues in the past.

Comment: Baldrick, Im not binding anything to the SelectedItem, Im reading from it when I filter. 
Or I've tried binding to it, but it doesnt make any difference, and I dont need to so I dont.

Comment: What kind of object is IssuesView? And how/when/where is it updated? It seems like that object is pretty key to your problem - if you're losing the SelectedItem, I wonder if IssuesView is somehow being recreated in such a way that the objects it contains are not the same objects. If for example IssuesView is a List<YourClass> and it re-populates on tab change, it would end up with new YourClass instances and SelectedItem would reference a dead object and would therefore wipe out. Perhaps IsAsync=True forces a binding refresh on IssuesView which causes it to re-load with new data on tab change?

Comment: any help with this issue?